# MongoDB Primary keeps on crashing after about 2 weeks

Tags: ubuntu, cluster, mongodb, grafana

We are running a mongodb cluster on 3 virtual machines in azure. I setup the cluster myself and we have been using this for about a year now. A few months ago we experienced a mongodb crash on our primary. Luckily the secondary takes over and there's no harm on our platform. The problem is, since then the primary will crash about every two weeks.

We have these servers in Grafana with custom monitoring, and the moment before the crash the 'Time spent doing I/O' is fluctuating a lot and peaking higher than normal. A bit after that the server crashes with the following error:

```
2017-08-27T23:29:31.537+0000 F -        [NetworkInterfaceASIO-BGSync-0] std::exception::what(): Resource temporarily unavailable
Actual exception type: std::system_error

 0x1556b32 0x1555e42 0x1ce5506 0x1ce5551 0x14e0a35 0x14e1258 0x12d996e 0x12da16e 0x12da8a8 0x12cd06c 0x12c2a38 0x12c3f9a 0x12c4cd9 0x12c0f85 0x128c858 0x129ee53 0x129f48d 0x1576824 0x1576a21 0x12b75fb 0x1d00200 0x7fa0454f56ba 0x7fa04522b3dd
----- BEGIN BACKTRACE -----
{"backtrace":[{"b":"400000","o":"1156B32","s":"_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo"},{"b":"400000","o":"1155E42"},{"b":"400000","o":"18E5506","s":"_ZN10__cxxabiv111__terminateEPFvvE"},{"b":"400000","o":"18E5551"},{"b":"400000","o":"10E0A35","s":"_ZN5mongo10ThreadPool25_startWorkerThread_inlockEv"},{"b":"400000","o":"10E1258","s":"_ZN5mongo10ThreadPool8scheduleESt8functionIFvvEE"},{"b":"400000","o":"ED996E","s":"_ZN5mongo8executor22ThreadPoolTaskExecutor23scheduleIntoPool_inlockEPNSt7__cxx114listISt10shared_ptrINS1_13CallbackStateEESaIS6_EEERKSt14_List_iteratorIS6_ESD_St11unique_lockISt5mutexE"},{"b":"400000","o":"EDA16E","s":"_ZN5mongo8executor22ThreadPoolTaskExecutor23scheduleIntoPool_inlockEPNSt7__cxx114listISt10shared_ptrINS1_13CallbackStateEESaIS6_EEERKSt14_List_iteratorIS6_ESt11unique_lockISt5mutexE"},{"b":"400000","o":"EDA8A8"},{"b":"400000","o":"ECD06C","s":"_ZN5mongo8executor20NetworkInterfaceASIO7AsyncOp6finishERKNS_10StatusWithINS0_21RemoteCommandResponseEEE"},{"b":"400000","o":"EC2A38","s":"_ZN5mongo8executor20NetworkInterfaceASIO18_completeOperationEPNS1_7AsyncOpERKNS_10StatusWithINS0_21RemoteCommandResponseEEE"},{"b":"400000","o":"EC3F9A","s":"_ZN5mongo8executor20NetworkInterfaceASIO20_completedOpCallbackEPNS1_7AsyncOpE"},{"b":"400000","o":"EC4CD9"},{"b":"400000","o":"EC0F85"},{"b":"400000","o":"E8C858","s":"_ZN4asio6detail14strand_service8dispatchINS0_7binder2IRSt8functionIFvSt10error_codemEES5_mEEEEvRPNS1_11strand_implERT_"},{"b":"400000","o":"E9EE53","s":"_ZN4asio6detail14strand_service8dispatchINS0_17rewrapped_handlerINS0_7binder2INS0_7read_opINS_19basic_stream_socketINS_2ip3tcpENS_21stream_socket_serviceIS8_EEEENS_17mutable_buffers_1ENS0_14transfer_all_tENS0_15wrapped_handlerINS_10io_service6strandESt8functionIFvSt10error_codemEENS0_26is_continuation_if_runningEEEEESI_mEESK_EEEEvRPNS1_11strand_implERT_"},{"b":"400000","o":"E9F48D","s":"_ZN4asio6detail23reactive_socket_recv_opINS_17mutable_buffers_1ENS0_7read_opINS_19basic_stream_socketINS_2ip3tcpENS_21stream_socket_serviceIS6_EEEES2_NS0_14transfer_all_tENS0_15wrapped_handlerINS_10io_service6strandESt8functionIFvSt10error_codemEENS0_26is_continuation_if_runningEEEEEE11do_completeEPvPNS0_19scheduler_operationERKSF_m"},{"b":"400000","o":"1176824","s":"_ZN4asio6detail9scheduler10do_run_oneERNS0_11scoped_lockINS0_11posix_mutexEEERNS0_21scheduler_thread_infoERKSt10error_code"},{"b":"400000","o":"1176A21","s":"_ZN4asio6detail9scheduler3runERSt10error_code"},{"b":"400000","o":"EB75FB"},{"b":"400000","o":"1900200"},{"b":"7FA0454EE000","o":"76BA"},{"b":"7FA045124000","o":"1073DD","s":"clone"}],"processInfo":{ "mongodbVersion" : "3.2.16", "gitVersion" : "056bf45128114e44c5358c7a8776fb582363e094", "compiledModules" : [], "uname" : { "sysname" : "Linux", "release" : "4.4.0-92-generic", "version" : "#115-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 10 09:04:33 UTC 2017", "machine" : "x86_64" }, "somap" : [ { "elfType" : 2, "b" : "400000", "buildId" : "B4C77D1B42936B23E28A2739927CB25274DB2D96" }, { "b" : "7FFE41517000", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "F23E2C79BCC8E97B12E1BB62A1BF196F8423FC40" }, { "b" : "7FA04647A000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "675F454AD6FD0B6CA2E41127C7B98079DA37F7B6" }, { "b" : "7FA046036000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "2DA08A7E5BF610030DD33B70DB951399626B7496" }, { "b" : "7FA045E2E000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "F951C1E0765FCAE48F82CAFE35D1ADD36D6C9AF9" }, { "b" : "7FA045C2A000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "0FC788F0861846257B5F1773FBD438E95DFC1032" }, { "b" : "7FA045921000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "FF7A33D389E756CA381A8189291A968EA5E1F4F8" }, { "b" : "7FA04570B000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "68220AE2C65D65C1B6AAA12FA6765A6EC2F5F434" }, { "b" : "7FA0454EE000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "27F189EF8DB8C3734C6A678E6EF3CB0B206D58B2" }, { "b" : "7FA045124000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "088A6E00A1814622219F346B41E775B8DD46C518" }, { "b" : "7FA0466E3000", "path" : "/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "9157F205547F0EB588E2AB1F2F120B74253A43EA" } ] }}
 mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x32) [0x1556b32]
 mongod(+0x1155E42) [0x1555e42]
 mongod(_ZN10__cxxabiv111__terminateEPFvvE+0x6) [0x1ce5506]
 mongod(+0x18E5551) [0x1ce5551]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo10ThreadPool25_startWorkerThread_inlockEv+0x965) [0x14e0a35]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo10ThreadPool8scheduleESt8functionIFvvEE+0x358) [0x14e1258]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo8executor22ThreadPoolTaskExecutor23scheduleIntoPool_inlockEPNSt7__cxx114listISt10shared_ptrINS1_13CallbackStateEESaIS6_EEERKSt14_List_iteratorIS6_ESD_St11unique_lockISt5mutexE+0x1FE) [0x12d996e]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo8executor22ThreadPoolTaskExecutor23scheduleIntoPool_inlockEPNSt7__cxx114listISt10shared_ptrINS1_13CallbackStateEESaIS6_EEERKSt14_List_iteratorIS6_ESt11unique_lockISt5mutexE+0x3E) [0x12da16e]
 mongod(+0xEDA8A8) [0x12da8a8]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo8executor20NetworkInterfaceASIO7AsyncOp6finishERKNS_10StatusWithINS0_21RemoteCommandResponseEEE+0x18C) [0x12cd06c]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo8executor20NetworkInterfaceASIO18_completeOperationEPNS1_7AsyncOpERKNS_10StatusWithINS0_21RemoteCommandResponseEEE+0x378) [0x12c2a38]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo8executor20NetworkInterfaceASIO20_completedOpCallbackEPNS1_7AsyncOpE+0x6A) [0x12c3f9a]
 mongod(+0xEC4CD9) [0x12c4cd9]
 mongod(+0xEC0F85) [0x12c0f85]
 mongod(_ZN4asio6detail14strand_service8dispatchINS0_7binder2IRSt8functionIFvSt10error_codemEES5_mEEEEvRPNS1_11strand_implERT_+0x88) [0x128c858]
 mongod(_ZN4asio6detail14strand_service8dispatchINS0_17rewrapped_handlerINS0_7binder2INS0_7read_opINS_19basic_stream_socketINS_2ip3tcpENS_21stream_socket_serviceIS8_EEEENS_17mutable_buffers_1ENS0_14transfer_all_tENS0_15wrapped_handlerINS_10io_service6strandESt8functionIFvSt10error_codemEENS0_26is_continuation_if_runningEEEEESI_mEESK_EEEEvRPNS1_11strand_implERT_+0x6D3) [0x129ee53]
 mongod(_ZN4asio6detail23reactive_socket_recv_opINS_17mutable_buffers_1ENS0_7read_opINS_19basic_stream_socketINS_2ip3tcpENS_21stream_socket_serviceIS6_EEEES2_NS0_14transfer_all_tENS0_15wrapped_handlerINS_10io_service6strandESt8functionIFvSt10error_codemEENS0_26is_continuation_if_runningEEEEEE11do_completeEPvPNS0_19scheduler_operationERKSF_m+0x1ED) [0x129f48d]
 mongod(_ZN4asio6detail9scheduler10do_run_oneERNS0_11scoped_lockINS0_11posix_mutexEEERNS0_21scheduler_thread_infoERKSt10error_code+0x304) [0x1576824]
 mongod(_ZN4asio6detail9scheduler3runERSt10error_code+0xC1) [0x1576a21]
 mongod(+0xEB75FB) [0x12b75fb]
 mongod(+0x1900200) [0x1d00200]
 libpthread.so.0(+0x76BA) [0x7fa0454f56ba]
 libc.so.6(clone+0x6D) [0x7fa04522b3dd]
-----  END BACKTRACE  -----
2017-08-27T23:29:31.487+0000 I COMMAND  [conn11335] command admin.$cmd command: isMaster { ismaster: true, client: { driver: { name: "nodejs", version: "2.2.24" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "linux", architecture: "x64", version: "4.4.0-71-generic" }, platform: "Node.js v4.8.3, LE, mongodb-core: 2.1.8" } } keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:0 reslen:342 locks:{} protocol:op_query 23099ms
```

I don't know where to start exactly to debug this error. The weird thing is that the 2 secondaries never experience downtime even though they have the exact same config.

If needed, my mongo config:

```
storage:
  dbPath: /data
  journal:
    enabled: true

systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0

security:
   keyFile: /etc/mongo-keyfile

replication:
   replSetName: rs0
   oplogSizeMB: 150
```

Each server is running Ubuntu 16.04 on azure with mongo on version 3.2 with the latest release (currently 3.2.16)

Comment: What specific version of MongoDB server and O/S are you running?

Comment: I should have mentioned that, will update my post: ubuntu 16.04 with mongodb 3.2 on latest release

Answer (score 1):

We had exactly the same occur in our environment. We discovered that another daily job was starting at that time and consuming all the system memory, occasionally causing MongoDB to crash with the same error + stack trace.

We're running a three-server replica set with MongoDB 3.4.9 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.